# Braid groups for ropes?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, braid-groups

What is the proper braid theoretic treatment of rope construction? Any are there any good references/sources? It would seem that they are something like the Artin braid group, but instead of operating on `n` points arranged in a straight line, it has points arranged in a circle, possibly multiple concentric circles (core, intermediate, outer sheath). But I haven't been able to find much extant exposition of it in terms of the underlying math.

[image: Rope constructions]
([rope picture source](https://www.maximropes.com/home/tech_info/rope_constructions/) )

Comment: The circle arrangement is irrelevant.  Just line them up in any way you want and it becomes the standard braid group.

Comment: @Ruy I don't want to ignore the extra structure as irrelevant, if there is some extra structure here. I think there is at least one relation which holds in a circular arranged braid group that doesn't hold in the standard braid group? (In the circular arrangement on, say, 4 strands, there should be a move "swap41" for "swap #1 and #4, with #4 going underneath #1" which should obey the usual Artin relations with respect to the moves "swap34" = "swap #3 and #4, #3 underneath" and "swap12" = "swap #1 and #2, #1 underneath"; i.e., "swap41"."swap12"."swap41" = "swap12"."swap41"."swap12".)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is similar (maybe the same?) as a "mixed braid group", in which certain strands must always end up in certain positions. (I.e. the "core" strands must start and end in the "core" positions, and the outer strands must end up on the outside.) In the mixed braid group, the strands from different parts are allowed to interact inside the braid, but must end up in their proper parts again at the end.